# Can a website have two different search paths, one dedicated and one global?

Tags: usability, search, web, best-practice, mental-models

I am building a moderation portal - basically users can report dubious behaviour, which gets flagged. The moderator needs to audit each flagged item on the moderation portal.

My question comes around the search functionality. Since the main objective of the portal is to audit flagged items, some people want to have a separate search just for those flagged items -  - which will appear just above the table of flagged items -  as the user will want to search while they are in "audit state".

Then for the rest of the site the moderator might want to search for users and other things, there would be a global search which would appear as a magnifying glass in the navigation.

Does this seem redundant? Is this confusing for the user to have to search fields that search for different things or is it better to focus on the main user scenario of dealing with flagged items and therefor having a dedicated search makes the moderator's life easier.

Comment: Are moderators expert users / professionals, or is this a site like StackExchange where moderators are volunteer community users?

Comment: These will be professional moderators

Answer (score 2):

GitHub does this quite well. When you're in a repo, the search field is set to search that repo with the option to change it to 'global'. When you're on a global page it defaults to global search, with the option to change it to 'users', 'help', etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about a single field search with some options close by (checkbox or listbox "search in flagged only") ?
If you don't have too many entries it can be a good solution.

Anyway if you have multiple research field (but I woulnd't recommand it) you should indicate clearly what the search is about "Research in flagged only" in the field. (look at google page)

Comment: This is what I am suggesting, incorporating a filter to ease the search. Other team mates feel that because our primary task is to moderate flagged items, while they are on that page, flagged items should have their own search right there when the user needs it. Can you explain why you don't recommend having two search fields?

Comment: If both search fields are in the same page, it can confuse the user (he will use one field but not understand why it's not working, then he will find the second. Conclusion: loosing time for each new moderators) Look at google results, do they have one field for each category ? (image, web, etc.) no but the pre-selected is the most used : Web. Less is more [clear].